# How to proper set up Vitest UI?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, vuejs3, vitest

I'm working on a project with Vue3 - Composition API, which initially stated Vue CLI  and Jest. After a while we migrated to Vite, and now we made the switch to Vitest (instead of Jest). For the beginning the set-up seems to go fine and I wrote several unit-tests. No problems with that, But now, I just want to try the new Vitest UI. I've installed it according to documentation: npm i -D @vitest/ui and after that run: vitest --ui

The problem here is I get an error which seems to be in the library Vitest itself:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')
at configureServer (file:///work/node_modules/@vitest/ui/dist/index.js:11:29)
at _createServer (file:///work/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-a178814b.js:63375:30)
at async createVitest (file:///work/node_modules/vitest/dist/vendor-cli-api.70680cd5.js:14365:18)
at async startVitest (file:///work/node_modules/vitest/dist/vendor-cli-api.70680cd5.js:20757:15)
at async start (file:///work/node_modules/vitest/dist/cli.js:106:17)
```

Any ideea what seems to be the problem here ?